# Change the font size from one component to another component

Tags: ember.js

I want to change the font size from one component to another component.
I have component - `change-font-size`.

```
<h3>change-font-size.hbs</h3>
<button>+</button><button>-</button>
```

And component - `example-text`.

```
<h3>example-text.hbs</h3>
<p class="special-text">some text</p>.
```

Component `change-font-size` does not see html DOM of `example-text` component.

*Ember* generated the DOM dynamically, and we don't have *document.ready*.

An example of what I need - http://ruseller.com/lessons/les748/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [example](https://ember-twiddle.com/b5be7c345d0dcff67ede)

Ember and for that matter React you should not be manipulate the DOM directly.

What you need todo is setup your `change-font-size` component to pass down the `font-size` to the components nested components. The `change-font-size` would be the buttons to increase and decrease the font-size.

**components/change-font-size.js**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  fontSize: 14,

  actions: {
    increaseFontSize() {
      return this.set('fontSize', this.get('fontSize') + 1);
    },

    decreaseFontSize() {
      return this.set('fontSize', this.get('fontSize') - 1);
    }
  }
});
```

**templates/components/change-font-size.hbs**

```
<button {{action 'increaseFontSize'}}> + </button>
<button {{action 'decreaseFontSize'}}> - </button>

{{yield fontSize}}
```

**components/example-text.js**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

  fontSize: 14,

  displayFontSize: Ember.computed('fontSize', function(){
    let newFontSize = parseInt(this.get('fontSize'), 10);
    return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(`font-size: ${newFontSize}px`);
  }),

  h3FontSize: Ember.computed('fontSize', function(){
    // keep the h3 font size 50% bigger.
    let newFontSize = parseInt(this.get('fontSize') * 1.5, 10);
    return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(`font-size: ${newFontSize}px`);
  })
});
```

**templates/components/example-text.hbs**
    The Title
    some text.

Then uses the components this way. You want to pass the fontSize from the change-font-size component to the to any nested components.

```
{{#change-font-size as |fontSize|}}
    {{example-text fontSize=fontSize}}
{{/change-font-size}}
```